# Reordenar y renombrar claves de objeto dinámicamente en base a ordenamientos y nombres almacenados - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, vue.js

Recibo un objeto con un conjunto de datos con sus respectivas claves pero estas llegan en un orden incorrecto, al mismo tiempo los nombres de estas claves también son erróneos. Los valores de estas claves son correctos. Necesito reordenar el objeto y cambiarle el nombre a las claves.
El orden de las claves así como sus nombres correctos están almacenados en dos variables distintas.

```
// Objeto que recibo desordenado y con los nombres de las claves erróneos
let objRecibido = [
    {
        "CampoX": ValorX,
        "CampoZ": ValorZ,
        "CampoV": ValorV,
    },
    {
        "CampoX": ValorX,
        "CampoZ": ValorZ,
        "CampoV": ValorV,
    }
];

// Objeto con el orden correcto de las claves
let camposOrdenados = [
    "CampoZ",
    "CampoV",
    "CampoX"
];

// Objeto con el nombre correcto de las claves
let camposTitulos = [
    "PrimerCampo",
    "SegundoCampo",
    "TercerCampo"
];
```

El resultado que deseo sería

```
// Nuevo objeto ordenado y con los nombre de las claves cambiados
let newSortRenameObj = [
    {
        "PrimerCampo": ValorZ,
        "SegundoCampo": ValorV,
        "TercerCampo": ValorX,
    },
    {
        "PrimerCampo": ValorZ,
        "SegundoCampo": ValorV,
        "TercerCampo": ValorX,
    }
];
```

Reeditado: Llegué a este punto, pero no sé como reasignar la posición ni el nombre

```
camposOrdenados.forEach(function(key) {          
   objRecibido= objRecibido.filter(function(item) {
      let itemKey = Object.keys(item)
      for (let index = 0; index < itemKey.length; index++) {
         if(itemKey[index] == key) { 
           console.log("indice "+key+" igualado en iteración de camposOrdenados: " + index)   
           console.log("posición índice camposOrdenados: "+ Object.values(camposOrdenados).indexOf(key)) 
                    
           //Asignar la posición de la clave de objRecibido en la posición Object.values(camposOrdenados).indexOf(key)
           //Cambiar nombre de la clave
         }                 
      }                
   })
});
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? ¿Cuál es el problema o dificultad con lo que has intentado? Recuerda que para poder ayudarte has de mostrar un [mcve] válido donde expongas los detalles de tu intento y el problema con dicho intento. De lo contrario parece que quieres que alguien lo haga todo por ti. Saludos

Comment: Si, Reedité la pregunta. No consigo pasar de ahí

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres hacer es lo que muestras un simple `map` basta para obtener los nuevos campos ordenados.

Usas el map e iteras en el array de objeto que te llega. Basándote en las estructuras que ya tienes definidas, de campos ordenados y campos con claves correctas, creas los nuevos objetos y los agregas a un nuevo array.

Te adjunto una muestra usando tu código:

```js
let objRecibido = [
    {
        "CampoX": 'ValorX',
        "CampoZ": 'ValorZ',
        "CampoV": 'ValorV',
    },
    {
        "CampoX": 'ValorX',
        "CampoZ": 'ValorZ',
        "CampoV": 'ValorV',
    }
];

// Objeto con el orden correcto de las claves
let camposOrdenados = [
    "CampoZ",
    "CampoV",
    "CampoX"
];

// Objeto con el nombre correcto de las claves
let camposTitulos = [
    "PrimerCampo",
    "SegundoCampo",
    "TercerCampo"
];


let objCorrecto = objRecibido.map(element =>{
  const obj = {}
  camposOrdenados.forEach((campo,i) => {
    obj[camposTitulos[i]] = element[campo]
  })
  return obj
})

console.log(objCorrecto)
```

Comment: Perfecto! Muchas gracias @jaime